# All posts display default index.html

Tags: posts, admin

I am setting up a wordpress blog on a Ubuntu LAMP with ispconfig 3 and freedns.afraid.org. I have everything set up, can log in to domain/wp-admin to create posts, etc. But the blog views as the "Welcome to your website!" ispconfig page. What should I check to figure out what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete or rename index.html as it's the default file served if it's available. This should then allow the server to start displaying your site files.

Comment: I will try this an let you know how it goes. Thanks!